# How to add a print button to a web page

Tags: php, css

On one of my pages in my website(coded in php), i'm trying to add 2 (even more) print buttons each one printing a portion of the webpage. For example, on a page there is a table with some values and 2 graphs underneath it. I would like to add 2 print buttons, one button printing the table and the other one printing both the graphs. I've found this [Example](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/03/13/CSSBasedPrintingTip.aspx) but could not understand clearly. Any help or examples would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting different `@media` print styles before calling window.print, depending on which button is clicked.

Comment: @Piskvor, even simpler: just create some previous rules and switch a classname :)

Comment: @F. Calderan: Or that. Same thing, principially :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple idea is to create some previous css printing rules ad hoc, e.g.

```
.printtable * { display : none; }
.printtable table { display : block; }
```

and

```
.printtableandgraph * { display : none; }
.printtableandgraph img { display : block; }
```

then the two buttons should add a `.printtable` and a `.printtableandgraph` class for the body element (or other element containing your table and graphs) just before `window.print()` statement

(if user click twice or more on the same print button check previously if the element has already set that class name)

Answer (score 16):

This is html/javascript code that will launch the browser's Print dialog when clicked.

```
<button onClick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```

Comment: this code alone is just printing the whole page... it can't be used to choose which part of the page should be printed.

Comment: @Ed Manet yes, i knew about the window.print() function..but it doesn't select a portion of the webpage

Comment: I don't think any browser has the capability of printing just a portion of the page.  It will print whatever you display on the page.  So either open a new window with the contents you want to print, or hide all the content you don't want to print.

Answer (score 10):

If your table is inside a **div** with **id**='printTable' use:

```
<a href="#null" onclick="printContent('printTable')">Click to print table</a>
```

EDIT: Here is the function "printContent()"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function printContent(id){
str=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
newwin=window.open('','printwin','left=100,top=100,width=400,height=400')
newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Print Page</TITLE>\n')
newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('else{\n')
newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000)\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')
newwin.document.write(str)
newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
newwin.document.close()
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! The only thing I had to add was to include the CSS sheet to keep the formating. (`newwin.document.write('<HTML><HEAD> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"CSS/style.css\"/>')`)

Answer (score 2):

Print Button

```
<button onClick="window.print()">Print this page</button>`
```

Use This code for print any webpage there is only one draw back its print all the button and menu bar.

Comment: How is this answer different from [Ed Manet's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11634203/851811) one?

Answer (score 0):

To print a portion of the page, you can use a print.css and the print button for a quick and simple approach.

1. Set up print.css file and include:

```css
     body {visibility:hidden;}
     .print {visibility:visible;}
```

2. Add **the .print class** to the appropriate portions of your page.
3. Add button:

```html
<button onClick="window.print()">Print this page »</button>
```

Print results are neat and clean.