# Charts not responding on the web page after printing them

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634153/how-to-add-a-print-button-to-a-web-page). I've successfully added a button to my php web page which works fine by printing all the graphs in the page at once. I've done the following way

```
function printdiv(printpage)
{
var headstr = '<html><head><title>Graphs</title></head>'+'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/template.css" />'+'<body><br/><br/><br/>';
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
die();
}


<input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt"   onClick="printdiv('graphs');" value="Graphs">
```

One issue i have now is, when i click the print button the preview pops up, once the printing is done, all the highcharts in that page become inactive (say when i move the cursor over the chart it and try to do something it doesnt respond until i refresh the page). Any clue whats happening here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have changed innerHTML, all the event listeners (to handle use interactions with your chart in this case,) have been removed at the same time.

You can try to generate a popup window to place your `headstr+newstr+footstr`, or use a more elegant approach, such as CSS media selector, to prevent this problem.

Comment: i've succeeded in printing only the elements of the body when i click on a button. I've linked this css to my webpage `@media print { body { font-size: 10pt } div#two{display:none;} }`. but what to do if i want to add another button which prints out only head contents?

Comment: @ven You can hide everything except you chosen ones in the page when print using css. like `*{ display: none; } .print{ display: block; }`